# Proof that expression is integer, $\frac{(3n)!}{6^nn!}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Can you help me with this exercises?

## Proof that expression is integer,

$$\frac{(3n)!}{6^nn!}$$

I've tried for induction!!

$p(1):\frac{(3)!}{6}=1 $

for $p(k)=\frac{(3k)!}{6^kk!}$

for $p(k+1)=\frac{(3k+3)!}{6^{k+1}(k+1)!}$

where,

$$\frac{(3k+3)(3k+2)(3k+1)(3k)!}{6^k.6(k+1)(k!)},$$For hypothesis:
$$\frac{(3k+2)(3k+1)}{2},$$

How can I follow??

help me??

Comment: That means the product of two consecutive number is always even. Can you see why?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: $3k + 2$ and $3k + 1$ are consecutive integers

Comment: ohh,, ok, , can i do it,, 2q/2=q?

Comment: @YobaniOrdoñez What do you mean by $\frac{2q}{2} = q$?

Comment: how  are cosecutive number, one should be even,, or no??

Comment: @YobaniOrdoñez By "consecutive", I mean that two integers are adjacent to each other. For example, $1$ and $2$ are consecutive, while $1$ and $3$ are not. Observe that the natural numbers are $1$(odd), $2$(even), $3$(odd), $4$(even), $\cdots$. So one of $3k + 2$ and $3k + 1$ must be multiple of $2$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

\begin{align*}
\frac{(3n)!}{6^n n!}
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(3i-2)(3i-1)(3i)}{6i} \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{(3i-2)(3i-1)}{2}
\end{align*}
Now, justify why $\frac{(3i-2)(3i-1)}{2}$ is an integer, and then $\frac{(3n)!}{6^n n!}$ is the product of a bunch of integers, and hence is itself an integer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want induction. From where you stopped, note that
if $k$ is odd then $3k+1$ is even; whereas if $k$ is even then $3k+2$ is also even. So the quotient
$$
\frac{(3k+2)(3k+1)}{2} 
$$
is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Let us begin with the basic case, $n=0$. The expression $\frac{(3n)!}{6^nn!}$ is an integer for $n=0$, so the basic case is valid. 
Let us assume that the statement is true for $n$, and that the integer it results in is equal to $k$. Our goal is to prove it true for $n+1$.
We first plug in $n+1$ for the expression.
\begin{align*}
\frac{[3(n+1)]!}{6^{n+1}(n+1)!}
\end{align*}
Using factorial properties and properties of exponents, we can rewrite it like this:
\begin{align*}
\frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)(3n)!}{6\cdot6^n(n+1)n!}
\end{align*}
Using our inductive hypothesis, we can rewrite the expression as:
\begin{align*}
k\cdot\frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{6(n+1)} 
\end{align*}
We can use algebraic simplification to completely remove the $3n+3$ out of the numerator along with $n+1$, leaving us with:
\begin{align*}
k\cdot\frac{(3n+2)(3n+1)}{2} 
\end{align*}
Notice that $3n+2$ and $3n+1$ are consecutive integers, and the product of consecutive integers is always even, since one of the two integers must be even. This leads to the claim that
\begin{align*}
\frac{(3n+2)(3n+1)}{2}\in\mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
This means that the entire expression is an integer, and the expression is an integer for $n+1$, finishing the proof.